# Unable to send broadcast to closed app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast, android-lvl

We've developed an app that requieres a second app (pro key app) to validate its license. The main (free app) request, via broadcast, to the pro key app to check the license.
The problem is that when the pro key app is closed it never receives the broadcast sent by the main app, to workaround this problem I have to open the pro key app before and then try to verify the license again.

Here is how the main app sends it:

```
public static void checkLicense(Context context) {
    ...
    Intent checkLicenseIntent = new Intent(Constants.CHECK_LICENSE_INTENT);
    context.sendBroadcast(checkLicenseIntent);
    ...
}
```

Here is the pro key app's manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ar.com.myapp.prokey"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.0.0.1" >

    <permission
        android:name="ar.com.myapp.prokey.CheckLicense"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="ar.com.myapp.ReceiveLicenseCheckResponse" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="ar.com.myapp.prokey.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="ar.com.myapp.prokey.CheckLicenseReceiver"
            android:permission="ar.com.myapp.prokey.CheckLicense" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="ar.com.myapp.prokey.CHECK_LICENSE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="ar.com.myapp.prokey.LicenseVerificationService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Is this the way to communicate the apps? Should the broadcast wake up the key pro app or not?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app is in "stopped" state it will not be able to receive any intents. You need to "activate" the app by activating any of its components. If you use setComponent() on the broadcasted intent, the system will activate the app before sending the intent.

Add this line to your code:

```
Intent checkLicenseIntent = new Intent(Constants.CHECK_LICENSE_INTENT);
checkLicenseIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("ar.com.myapp.prokey", "ar.com.myapp.prokey.CheckLicenseReceiver"));
context.sendBroadcast(checkLicenseIntent);
```

You can read more on this article: https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/12/05/activating-applications/

Answer (score 1):

> Should the broadcast wake up the key pro app or not?

If by "wake up" you mean "fork a process for it", then yes, it will, once you fix your `<intent-filter>`, by getting rid of the two `<category>` elements, as your `Intent` that you are broadcasting does not have a category. Categories are rarely used with broadcasts.

Also bear in mind that [custom permissions have security issues](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/blob/master/PERMS.md).

Comment: I've removed the categories and the problem persists